# Rebuilding Index - sort in temp db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

What is the significance of `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` when working with indexes on a table of significant size (20GB plus)?

Where else does sorting take place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It depends.**

The options are -

- Sort in the destination file group (normally `PRIMARY` on the DB the index is on)
- Sort in `TempDB`

If your `TempDB` is on a different disk array and not active, you could see a performance increase.  There are also space considerations.

[There's a pretty good article on MSDN about this topic here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188281.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What it does is instead of utilizing the target database to do the intermediate sorts for creating and rebuilding the index, it uses `tempdb` for this task.  You will most likely see performance gains as far as duration of the time it would normally take, but it will also increase the amount of disk space used.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).